# Send Intent from Activity to another Activity with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I have an Activity where I enter a phone number and a message and when I click on the send Button, I want to display the message and number I entered in the layout of another Activity which has a RecyclerView. I have tried to use an Intent but it displays "NUMBER" and "NUMBER" in both TextViews.
This is some of the code below.

```
public class NewMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private String message, number;
private EditText mComposeMessage, mPhoneNumber;
private Button mSendButton, mCancelButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_message_layout);

    mPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number_et);
    mComposeMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.compose_et);
    mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);
    mCancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);

    number = mPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
    message = mComposeMessage.getText().toString();

    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);
    mCancelButton.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);
}

private View.OnClickListener mButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.send_button:
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SentActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.key_message), message);
                intent.putExtra("NUMBER", number);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.cancel_button:
                break;
        }
    }
};

}
```

This is my Adapter

```
public class SentMessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SentMessageAdapter.MessageHolder> {
private List<String> mMessages;

public static class MessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView mSentMessageTv;
    private TextView mRecipientNumberTv;
    private TextView mRecipientTv;

    public MessageHolder(View v){
        super(v);
        mSentMessageTv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sent_message_tv);
        mRecipientNumberTv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.recipient_number_tv);
        mRecipientTv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.recipient_tv);
    }
}

public SentMessageAdapter(List<String> messages){
    mMessages = messages;
}

@Override
public MessageHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sent_list_item, parent, false);
    MessageHolder vH = new MessageHolder(v);
    return vH;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MessageHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mSentMessageTv.setText(mMessages.get(position));
    holder.mRecipientNumberTv.setText(mMessages.get(position));
    holder.mRecipientTv.setText(R.string.to);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMessages.size();
}

}
```

Activity where the text should be displayed

```
public class SentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = SentActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

final ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.message_recycler_list);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String message = null;

    if (extras != null){
        message = extras.getString(String.valueOf(R.string.key_message), String.valueOf("NUMBER"));
    }


    if (message == null){
        message = "text";
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, message);
    messages.add(0, message);


    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.message_recycler_view);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new SentMessageAdapter(messages);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Layout for the Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sent_message_tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    tools:text="Hello world"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipient_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="@string/to"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipient_number_tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in `onBindViewHolder` setting same text for `mSentMessageTv ` & `mRecipientNumberTv `

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing phone number edit text in onCreate;

```
number = mPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
```

And it will be set to whatever your text in XML (It's set to NUMBER I guess). You need to access this after user entered text, so put this line in on click listener.

Answer (score 0):

Get message and number value in onClick method not onCreate

```
switch (id) {
        case R.id.send_button:
number = mPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
message = mComposeMessage.getText().toString();

Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SentActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.key_message), message);
            intent.putExtra("NUMBER", number);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are Not getting value that you entered is because you are accessing edittext values in onCreate method where it has default value so you should use

```
    number = mPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
    message = mComposeMessage.getText().toString();
```

this in onClick Methods

```
   private View.OnClickListener mButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();

            switch (id) {
                case R.id.send_button:
                    number = mPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
                    message = mComposeMessage.getText().toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SentActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.key_message), message);
                    intent.putExtra("NUMBER", number);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case R.id.cancel_button:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I have fixed it now. I created a POJO class

```
public class Message {
private String mMessage;
private String mNumber;

public Message(String number, String message){
    mNumber = number;
    mMessage = message;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return mMessage;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return mNumber;
}

}
```

Then I changed the onBindViewHolder() to

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MessageHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mSentMessageTv.setText(mMessages.get(position).getMessage());
    holder.mRecipientNumberTv.setText(mMessages.get(position).getNumber());
    holder.mRecipientTv.setText(R.string.to);
}
```

I also changed to

```
String message = null;
    String number = null;

    if (extras != null){
        message = extras.getString(String.valueOf("MESSAGE"));
        number = extras.getString(String.valueOf("NUMBER"));

    }

    messages.add(new Message(number, message));
```

Finally, I changed all generics to

```
<Message>
```